# How to pass a new const value to jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, automated-tests

On my file I have a piece of code like:

```
const example = value.filter((name) => !oldname.includes(name))
```

But on my test I want to change the **const example** to something value specific for convenience. Theres is a a way to do that?

Comment: Set the appropriate values of `value` and `oldname`? Where do they come from?

Comment: if you want to update example after it has been created use let instead of const.

Comment: They come from some arrays in the file, @jonrsharpe.

Comment: I want to change the const example on the test file to something like const example = "somevalue" insted of having to run the entire filter and includes @rafael-gonzalez

Comment: Please give a [mre] that explains what you're trying to test here. If these are just constants in a file it's not clear what you think needs mocking.